# How to use React.forwardRef with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to write a component with props using `forwardRef`, like:

```js
const Greeting = React
  .forwardRef<
    HTMLDivElement,
    {name: string}>(
      (props, ref) => <div ref={ref}>{`Hello ${props.name}`}</div>,
    );
```

However, I got a error message.

```
TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Configuration:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.rules=[{
        test: /.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'ts-loader',
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
              plugins: [
                [
                  /**
                   * To suppost material ui's styled components selector
                   */
                  '@emotion',
                  {
                    importMap: {
                      '@mui/system': {
                        styled: {
                          canonicalImport: ['@emotion/styled', 'default'],
                          styledBaseImport: ['@mui/system', 'styled'],
                        },
                      },
                      '@mui/material/styles': {
                        styled: {
                          canonicalImport: ['@emotion/styled', 'default'],
                          styledBaseImport: ['@mui/material/styles', 'styled'],
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },]
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
    }
}
```

Is there some way to create a component with `props` and `ref` using typescript?

d.ts source code in React follow:

```js
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

```js
interface ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, ref: ForwardedRef<T>): ReactElement | null;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
    // explicit rejected with `never` required due to
    // https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36826
    /**
     * defaultProps are not supported on render functions
     */
     defaultProps?: never | undefined;
     /**
      * propTypes are not supported on render functions
      */
     propTypes?: never | undefined;
}
```

```js
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode | undefined };
```

I think it just add a `children` properties filed to my type. But why it eventually removes all the types define, remaining only the `children`？

Answer (score 1):

```
const Greeting = React
  .forwardRef<
    HTMLDivElement,
    {name: string}>(
      (props, ref) => <div ref={ref}>{`Hello ${props.name}`}</div>,
    );
```

Your prop should be type like that:

```
{name}: {name: string}
```

Comment: I mean the component can't pass the typescript compiling without using it.